# How can I verify my mobile number on Twitter?

Tags: twitter, verification

I can't add my mobile number, because the carrier isn't listed [in the device list](http://twitter.com/devices).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean getting the "Verified Account" badge on your profile?  If you do then you can't - it is closed to the public

http://support.twitter.com/groups/31-twitter-basics/topics/111-features/articles/119135-about-verified-accounts

EDIT:

With regards to the mobile verification - if your carrier is not available then read this article 
http://support.twitter.com/articles/41611-which-mobile-carriers-does-twitter-support

It means that you will probably be able to send texts to Twitter but not receive any.

Comment: The title needs to say "How can I verify my mobile number" instead, but that doesn't mean the answer has to 100% miss the mark given the explanation in the question body itself.

Comment: @VxJasonxV - I have updated my answer

Comment: Appreciate it. (1 more to go..)